# Does removing .php extension with .htaccess duplicate my pages?

Tags: php, .htaccess, hosting

I have just removed the .php extension of the files on my web adding this code to my .htaccess file (first line was already there when I first open the file):

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php71 .php .php5 .php4 .php3

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
</IfModule>
```

The fact is that now I can access to my site both ways, I mean by misite.com/shop and by misite.com/shop.php

Does this affect to my page SEO as one same page can be accessed by two differents ways or this won't mean any problem?

Another thing I would like to change is that when I click to my index site, it appears as mysite.com/index (as now I have removed the .php extension). How could I make it so that it shows only "mysite.com" whithout the "/index"?

Comment: You can always rewrite PHP files to not included the .php suffix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below code will help you to remove the `.php` extention and redirect it without `.php` format:

```
## hide .php extension snippet
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]
# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Here is the meta code for you to handle the SEO related problems. Use `rel="canonical"`, It is used to let the search engine know the original URL of the page. Below is an example for you, it will let the bots know that URL http://example.com/ is the actual URL of http://example.com/index

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/" />
```

In anchor text, `<a href="./">Home</a>` instead of `<a href="index.php">Home</a>`

I hope this answer will do for you.

Comment: Thanks sir, I added that code to my .htaccess and now when I type mysite.com/shop.php on the browser it inmediatly redirects to mysite.com/shop, just as I wanted. However, I didn't understand the use of that rel="canonical". Imagine I'm on my shop.php file, do I have to add <link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/shop.php" /> on the head of the document or <link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/shop" />? Thanks for your answer

Comment: It should be `<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/shop" />` because http://example.com/shop.php will redirect you to http://example.com/shop. I think you will not want the bots to go in the loop. @Luiscri

Comment: Okei, I will add it to every single file on my web. I have found that with this changes I have added my contact form has stopped working. It uses an action="submit.php" function when you click the submit button, and if I try to send a message it seems to be a problem because the mail won't send. It was working until I changed the .htaccess with what you gave me, is there any aditional implementation I need to do?

Comment: It is not working because your **/submit.php** will redirect it to **/submit** and after redirection, your `$_POST` variable will be empty. To remove this error, use `action="submit"` instead of `action="submit.php"`

Comment: Exactly! Thanks for your time sir, I thought it was gonna be something harder to fix. The last thing I have find out visiting my site is that I have and anchor who redirects to a specific element tagged with and id this way `<a href="shop.php#elementId"` and when I click on the anchor it makes the redirect correctly but the url appears with the tag (it appears this way mysite.com/shop#elementId). How can I remove that tag so that it only displays /shop as if I hadn't done the redirect to that element?

Comment: This will actually be another question. I don't know the exact answer but I can help you remove that.

Comment: Very good answer and help through comments ++ Hashtag cannot be removed by rewrite rules as that is handed on client side by browser and Javascript.

Comment: So is there a way to remove it via js?